# Why is my customized Windows Forms panel cant handle child controls?

Tags: windows, forms, controls, components, designer

I want extend an System.Windows.Forms.Panel(just inherit) and using a custom ControlDesigner.
I use a very minimalistic ControlDesigner implementation, just overwrite GetHitTest.
The problem is my custom panel instance is not ready to contains child controls any longer.
I play a little bit with AssociatedComponents but without effect. Remove custom designer attribute and it works great.
can someone help me to pin point whats wrong ???

> ```
> [Designer(typeof(MyPanelDesigner)), ToolboxItem(true)]
> public class MyPanel : System.Windows.Forms.Panel
> {
>         // empty except for OnPaint
> }
> ```

```
internal class DrawPanelDesigner : ControlDesigner
{
        private MyPanel ParentControl
        {
            get
            {
                return Control as MyPanel;
        }
    }

    public override System.Collections.ICollection AssociatedComponents
{
    get
    {
        return ParentControl.Controls;
        }
    }

    protected override bool GetHitTest(System.Drawing.Point point)
    {
        // hit detection for some owner drawed items in OnPaint
        point = ParentControl.PointToClient(point);
        var item = ParentControl.View.GetItemFromViewPoint(point.X, point.Y, true);
        return null != item;
    }
```

Comment: Please post a sample of the code you are having trouble with...

Comment: not a particular line of code is the problem. but i have changed my posting. btw i have much problems with the stackoverflow code editor. what a beast !

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong designer.  Try inheriting from the [ScrollableControlDesigner](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/fx/src/Designer/WinForms/System/WinForms/Design/PanelDesigner@cs/1/PanelDesigner@cs) instead:

```
internal class DrawPanelDesigner : ScrollableControlDesigner {

  public DrawPanelDesigner() {
    AutoResizeHandles = true;
  }

  private MyPanel ParentControl {
    get {
      return Control as MyPanel;
    }
  }

  protected Pen BorderPen {
    get {
      Color penColor = Control.BackColor.GetBrightness() < .5 ?
                       ControlPaint.Light(Control.BackColor) :
                       ControlPaint.Dark(Control.BackColor);
      Pen pen = new Pen(penColor);
      pen.DashStyle = DashStyle.Dash;
      return pen;
    }
  }

  protected virtual void DrawBorder(Graphics graphics) {
    Panel panel = (Panel)Component;
    if (panel == null || !panel.Visible) {
      return;
    }

    Pen pen = BorderPen;
    Rectangle rc = Control.ClientRectangle;
    rc.Width--;
    rc.Height--;

    graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rc);
    pen.Dispose();
  }

  protected override void OnPaintAdornments(PaintEventArgs pe) {
    Panel panel = (Panel)Component;
    if (panel.BorderStyle == BorderStyle.None) {
      DrawBorder(pe.Graphics);
    }
    base.OnPaintAdornments(pe);
  }
}
```